# How do I get navigation bar's dropdown to stay when hovering on its contents?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have come up with a simple navigation bar, and I have designed the most basic frame for its appearance. After reading up, I have managed to be able to create a dropdown when I hover on the main element (word).

How would I go about making the dropdown stay when I hover over the dropdown itself?

I tried using JS to hold the `opacity` at 1 when I hover over the dropdown, but it doesn't work because the dropdown itself is based off of `opacity`, and it will affect it regardless of whether I have initially hovered over the main element, since it's not `display:none`.

Also, another question is, in my "Servers" dropdown, I seem to be able to see only the "Server List", and not the other 2 in the `<ul>`, why is that so?

As for what I have come up with for what I managed to get working, this is my code:

```js
document.getElementById("server").onmouseover = function() {
 serverMouseOver()
 };
document.getElementById("server").onmouseout = function() {
 serverMouseOut()
 };
function serverMouseOver() {
 document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").className+="animated fadeIn";
 };
function serverMouseOut() {
 document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").className+="animated fadeOut";
 };
```

```css
.clearfix {
   clear: both;
   }

body
   {
   background-color: rgb(21,14,43);
   background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   min-height: 100%;
   background-position: center center;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
   
#steamlogomainbox:hover
   {
   width: 12vw;
   }
 
#gigalogo
   {
   width: 26vw;
   height: 8vw;
   margin: 0 0 0 2vw;
   padding: 0;
   }
   
#steamlogomainbox
   {
   width: 10.5vw;
   height: 7vw;
   float: right;
   background-color: #0B0D16; /*000c21*/
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
   clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
   margin: 0.2vw -1vw 0 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
   
#steamlogo
   {
   padding: 0.7vw 0 0 3vw;
   height: 5.6vw;
   }  

#navbarbox   
   {
   clear: both;
   display: block;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 3.5vw;
   padding: 0vw 0 0 0;
   margin: 0;
   }
#navbar, #navbar ul
   {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 3.5vw;
   display: flex;
   padding: 0 0 0 0;
   margin: 0;
   }
   
#navbar span
   {
   height: 3.5vw;
   display: block;
   transform: skewX(15deg);
   }
   
#navbar li
   {
   color: white;
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 1vw 3.95vw 1vw 3.95vw;
   margin: auto;
   text-align: center;
   color: red;
   font-size: 2.3vw;
   font-family: Jura;
   height: 2.5vw;
   transform: skewX(-15deg);
   }
   
#serverdropdownbox
   {
   display: block;
   opacity: 0;
   float: left;
   color: white;
   background-color: darkblue;
   width: 0;
   transform: skewX(15deg);
   }
   
#serverdropdowncontent
   {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 16vw;
   margin: 1vw 0 0 10.1vw;
   }
   
   
#serverdropdowncontent li
   {
   border: 1px solid white;
   font-size: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
   background-color: white;
   }
   
#server
   {
   background-color: blue;
   }
      
#communitydropdownbox
   {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   color: white;
   background-color: darkblue;
   width: 0;
   transform: skewX(15deg);
   }
   
#communitydropdowncontent
   {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 19.7vw;
   margin: 1vw 0 0 26vw;
   }
   
   
#communitydropdowncontent li
   {
   border: 1px solid white;
   font-size: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
   }
   
#community
   {
   background-color: brown;
   }   
#storedropdownbox
   {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   color: white;
   background-color: darkblue;
   width: 0;
   transform: skewX(15deg);
   }
   
#storedropdowncontent
   {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 13.6vw;
   margin: 1vw 0 0 45.65vw;
   }
   
   
#storedropdowncontent li
   {
   border: 1px solid white;
   font-size: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
   }
   
#store
   {
   background-color: blue;
   }   
#downloadsdropdownbox
   {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   color: white;
   background-color: darkblue;
   width: 0;
   transform: skewX(15deg);
   }
   
#downloadsdropdowncontent
   {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 19.8vw;
   margin: 1vw 0 0 59.2vw;
   }
   
   
#downloadsdropdowncontent li
   {
   border: 1px solid white;
   font-size: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
   }
   
#downloads
   {
   background-color: brown;
   }   
#contactdropdownbox
   {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   color: white;
   background-color: darkblue;
   width: 0;
   transform: skewX(15deg);
   }
   
#contactdropdowncontent
   {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 16vw;
   margin: 1vw 0 0 78.9vw;
   }
   
   
#contactdropdowncontent li
   {
   border: 1px solid white;
   font-size: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
   }
   
#contact
   {
   background-color: blue;
   }
   
.animated
   {
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
   }

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fadeOut {
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura" />
</head>

<body>


<!--Giga logo, top left-->
<img id="gigalogo"  src="images/gigalogo.png">

<!--Steam logo, top right-->
<div id="steamlogomainbox">
  <img id="steamlogo" src="images/steamlogo.png">
</div>

<!--navigation barrrrrr-->
<div id="navbarbox">
 <ul id="navbar">
  <a href="default.html"><li style="background-color: purple;"><span>Home</span></li></a>
  <a href="servers.html"><li id="server"><span>Servers</span></li></a>
  <a href="community.html"><li id="community"><span>Community</span></li></a>
  <a href="store.html"><li id="store"><span>Store</span></li></a>
  <a href="downloads.html"><li id="downloads"><span>Downloads</span></li></a>
  <a href="contact.html"><li id="contact"><span>Contact</span></li></a>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="serverdropdownbox">
 <ul id="serverdropdowncontent">
  <a href="serverlist.html"><li id="serverdropdownli">Server List</li></a>
  <li id="serverdropdownli">GigaDB</li>
  <li id="serverdropdownli">CS:GO</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="communitydropdownbox">
 <ul id="communitydropdowncontent">
  <a href="events.html"><li>Events</li></a>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="storedropdownbox">
 <ul id="storedropdowncontent">
  <li>Credits</li>
  <li>Items</li>
  <li>VIP</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="downloadsdropdownbox">
 <ul id="downloadsdropdowncontent">
  <li>TF2</li>
  <li>CS:GO</li>
  <li>Minecraft</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="contactdropdownbox">
 <ul id="contactdropdowncontent">
  <li>Contact Us</li>
  <li>Staff</li>
  <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/groups/gigagamings" target="_blank"><li>Steam Group</li></a>
  <li>Appeal Ban</li>
  <li>Links</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to revisit this with classes not id's.  After a view enter/leave it starts to look like `<div id="serverdropdownbox" class="animated fadeInanimated fadeInanimated fadeOutanimated fadeInanimated fadeInanimated fadeOutanimated fadeInanimated fadeInanimated fadeInanimated fadeOutanimated fadeInanimated fadeInanimated fadeInanimated fadeInanimated fadeInanimated fadeOutanimated fadeInanimated fadeInanimated fadeOutanimated fadeInanimated fadeOutanimated fadeInanimated fadeOut">`

Comment: Look  to add/remove those classes on the elements as you enter/leave them. You only have ONE id in that event listener so only that one animates. Look into something like `.classList.toggle("animated");`

Comment: Ok I'll read up on that